# Using a Dictionary as ValueMember in Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a `combobox`, where I would like to display a string as the `DisplayMember` and have a `Dictionary<string,string>` as the `ValueMember`. I have a list containing the objects with the string and dictionary, this List I use as `DataSource` for the `ComboBox`.

```
List<myObject> myList = new List<myObject>{
 new myObject {myDisplayMember = "TEXT", myValueMember = new Dictionary<string,string> {{"A","ABC"},{"D","DEF"}}}
};

myComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(myList, null);
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "myDisplayMember";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "myValueMember";
```

The `DisplayMember` works as expected and "TEXT" is shown in the `ComboBox`, but when I get the `ValueMember` I only get a string of "`myValueMember`", instead of the dictionary I'd like to get. Is what I'm trying possible, or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: How did you try to get the value member? Can you show the code? Are you looking at `SelectedValue` property or what? That should work. If you look at `ValueMember` property, obviously it will be a string which you specified.

Comment: Well, this was a stupid question. @SriramSakthivel, you are right. I wasn't looking at the SelectedValue.

Comment: Ha ha ha, Well, it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            var list = new List<ItemX>() { 
                new ItemX { Name = "a", Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "1", "2" },{"qqq","wwww"} } },
                new ItemX { Name = "b", Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "3", "4" } } },
                new ItemX { Name = "c", Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "5", "6" } } },
            };

            comboBox1.DataSource = list;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Dictionary";
        }

        private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            if ( comboBox1.SelectedValue != null )
            {
                var d = comboBox1.SelectedValue as Dictionary<string, string>;

                if ( d != null )
                {
                    var builder = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> p in d )
                    {
                        builder.AppendFormat( "key:{0} value:{1}\n", p.Key, p.Value );
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show( builder.ToString() );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ItemX
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
    }
}
```